# Javascript call when current string of 'methods' have finished processing

Tags: javascript

If I have some string of function().method().method() is there any way to have a function called by the constructor only after all the methods have processed without checking a state using a loop?

The reason is I am ajax'ing in a template to fill in a parent element but I divided up the methods for easier reading where each of these methods would affect the template. The template currently is activated later in the process to guarantee the parameters have been setup. What I would like to do is tell the entire instance to load the template once all the methods have finished executing.

Or if using a timeout is the only way, is something like this feasible:

```
function(...setTimeOut(if(state)Func()).method(state=false...)
```

Comment: code example?? question looks vague?

Comment: Its better to explain but I will try to explain it more reasonably :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very vague. But I think what you might be looking for is a proper chaining, promising library like [this](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) one.

Comment: Yes this is more or less what Im looking for. I may give up and setup a custom trigger 'done' method.

Answer (score 0):

if you mark your ajax call property `async : false` ,all calls will happen synchronously , you dont have to worry about.

async (default: true)
Type: Boolean
By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().

ref: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/